# Where can I find Rabbi Yehuda HaChassid's will online?

Tags: product-recommendation, death, internet, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Rabbi Yehuda HaChassid wrote a famous will.

The only place I was able to find it was on [Hebrewbooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/19500).

However, it's an old print and an incomplete one at that.

Is there somewhere the complete will?

Comment: Some would say you can't find his will ANYWHERE. It's a very controversial work, and some, notably the חתם סופר (Resp. OC:138), have cast doubt on its authenticity. See R' Yosef Engel in Ben Porat, vol. 2, Siman 11.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Wikisource - he.wikisource.org - צוואת רבי יהודה החסיד](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93). Can't vouch for its completeness, but it seems to be there.

Hat tip: Google.